# Odoo takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Tags: python, odoo-10

I am very new in Odoo and Python, I am creating a module, I define one of the modules as:

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    _name = 'todo.task.tag'
    name = fields.Char('Name', 40)
```

However, when I install the module it shows this error:

```
File "/mnt/extra-addons/todo_ui/models/models.py", line 65, in Tag
    name = fields.Char('Name', 40)
TypeError: __init__() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that you are trying to set the field Char size, you will need to specify it using the size named argument.

```
name = fields.Char('Name', size=40)
```